# Priority Indication Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to show a priority setting button using `HTML, CSS and jQuery` to set the priority as High/Medium/Low as shown in the attached images and want to show selected priority in full word in a label next to it. Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried below, but its design is not similar to what I have attached here.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:radio[name=priority]').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#text").html($(this).val());

    $('label[for=' + id + ']').checked = true;
  });
});
```

```css
[type="radio"]:checked + span:after {
border: none;
background-color: unset;
}
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span:before {
border: none;  
}

input[type="radio"] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  /*border: 2px solid #1FBED6;*/
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*to disable the default appearance of radio button*/
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:focus {
  /*no need, if you don't disable default appearance*/
  outline: none;
  /*to remove the square border on focus*/
}

#h:checked {
  /*no need, if you don't disable default appearance*/
  background-color: red;
}

#m:checked {
  /*no need, if you don't disable default appearance*/
  background-color: orange;
}

#l:checked {
  /*no need, if you don't disable default appearance*/
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked~span:first-of-type {
  color: white;
}

label span:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
  left: -27px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}

label span {
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
}
```

```html
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="radio" id="h" name="priority" value="High priority"/><span>H</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" id="m" name="priority" value="Moderate priority"/><span>M</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" id="l" name="priority" value="Low priority"/><span>L</span></label>
<div id="text"> </div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I implement in my code, it's looks like below:

[image]

Comment: Yes this is possible, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Check out this URL for reference. this will help you start up. The styling you will have to do yourself https://jsfiddle.net/8kLzj9gs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a fiddle for you - https://jsfiddle.net/fuzp6mL9/2/

Edited some of your CSS plus added a wrapper for the radio buttons. Feel free to change the color to w/e you need.

NOTE:

You'll need to put a wrapper around "#test" and "#text" to clear the floats. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

```
<div id="test">

  <label><input type="radio" id="h" name="priority" value="High priority" /><span>H</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" id="m" name="priority" value="Moderate priority" /><span>M</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" id="l" name="priority" value="Low priority" /><span>L</span></label>

</div>

<div id="text"> </div>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('input:radio[name=priority]').change(function()
    {
      
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#text").html($(this).val());

      $('label[for='+id+']').checked = true;
    });
});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;

}

input[type="radio"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#h:checked {
  background-color: red;
}

#m:checked {
  background-color: orange;
}

#l:checked {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span:first-of-type {
  color: white;
}

label {
  width: 35px;

  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

label span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}

#text,
#test {
  float: left;

}

#text {

  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#test {
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 26px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="test">

      <label><input type="radio" id="h" name="priority" value="High priority" /><span>H</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" id="m" name="priority" value="Moderate priority" /><span>M</span></label>
      <label><input type="radio" id="l" name="priority" value="Low priority" /><span>L</span></label>

    </div>


    <div id="text"> </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried this solution. But it displays inner circle also. I have attached image for the same along with the question. Can you help me to hide that also.

Comment: Add the following to the `input[type="radio"]` CSS style -   `-webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;`

Comment: Did you replace all the HTML/CSS w/ what I posted in my answer? If you check the fiddle you can see that it's what you wanted (minus the correct bg color). I'm not understanding the new issue